# How to model a n-n relationsship in cloud firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

Let's say I have an app where users will be shown articles that fit the users filter criterias. For every article, I want to save if the user already saw the article or not, to make sure it will not be shown again in the future (user could also like or dislike, but for the example, lets just say we only want to save if he read it). In an SQL database I could model it like this:

```
 ┌────────┐1        n┌─────────────┐n        1┌──────────┐
 │  user  ├──────────┤ user_article├──────────┤  article │
 └────────┘          ├─────────────┤          └──────────┘
                     │ user_id     │
                     │ article_id  │
                     │             │
                     │ read: bool  │
                     └─────────────┘
```

I could then simply select all articles that are relevant for a user that he has not read yet:

```
select * from article where <some_criterias> and article_id not in (select article_id from user_article where read = true)
```

And as soon as the user read the article, I just add a new entry to `user_article` and it's all good.

Now, how can I do the same thing in a noSQL database like Firestore?

I thought about just saving a subcollection to user with all articles that he read, but then how can I query all articles that are not in that subcollection? The `in` operator in firebase only supports up to 10 values (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries).

Obviously I could just retrieve ALL articles, and then filter on the client side - but this is very inefficient, since I have to pay per read operation and if there are many articles, this will be very expensive. What other options do I have?

Answer (score 0):

Firestore is not well suited for queries like this.  There is no way to accomplish this efficiently and at scale with a single query.

Firstly, Firestore does provide a way to exclude documents from a query.  Firestore indexes only perform inclusive query results.

Secondly, Firestore doesn't have any sort of subqueries that allow you to modify the result of a primary query.  You can only query documents in a single collection (or collection group) at a time.

With these two limitations in place, there's not much you can do except what you are doing right now - manually computing the difference in the code that performs the queries.

In cases where Firestore does not support their required queries, it is common to duplicate the data into a database that can (for example, [full text search](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search)).  You just have to make sure that the mirrored database can handle your expected load.  Firestore scales up for read operations much better than SQL databases.

Comment: Hmm i thought this will be the answer but hoped that there might be some clever outside-the-box solution... I'll try to look into cloud functions and maybe i can find a clever way to replicate the data to an sql db this way :) thanks!